# LLVM (golang): Unescaped global strings?

Tags: string, go, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm writing my own compiler using LLVM and I'm trying to implement string literals.
By the way, I'm also using LLVM bindings for Golang from tinygo: https://github.com/tinygo-org/go-llvm

this is how I create a global string pointer:

```golang
Builder.CreateGlobalStringPtr(str, "")
```

when I output the LLVM bitcode and disassemble it, the global string pointer looks like this:

```
@1 = private unnamed_addr constant [14 x i8] c"hello world\\n\00", align 1
```

when I use fmt.Println() to check the value of a string that I'm passing to the builder method it looks like this:

```
hello world\n
```

As you can see there's no extra back slash in the new line character. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: That's not a newline. The last four characters of the GlobalVariable are a d, a backslash, an n and a null. The last three characters of str are d, backslash and n.